# XML stop overwriting/save multiple entries

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-serialization

Currently I am using this code to create a XML File

```
       {
           XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
           TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
           sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
           writer.Close();
       }
```

The Problem is that it always overrides the entry I made before. How can I make multiple entries and save them (perhabs in a Combobox/DropDownList?).

Here is the rest of my Code (btnSave btnLoad)

```
        {
            try
            {
                Daten daten = new Daten();

                daten.GAME = txtGame.Text;
                daten.PLATFORM = txtPlatform.Text;
                daten.RELEASED = txtReleased.Text;

                SaveData.SaveDaten(daten, "gameregister.xml");

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists("gameregister.xml"))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Daten));
                FileStream read = new FileStream("gameregister.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                Daten daten = (Daten)xs.Deserialize(read);

                txtGame.Text = daten.GAME;
                txtPlatform.Text = daten.PLATFORM;
                txtReleased.Text = daten.RELEASED;

                read.Close();
            }
        }
```

ps: I have to use XML for this specific task.

Comment: Does that mean, you want to save several instances of `Daten` in one xml file? You know, XML needs to have a unique root element, so you cannot just append another to the same file. That means: you'd need to have a "Collection" of `Daten` to which you can add, from which you can remove, edit ... and then _always_ save all of it or nothing. It's a text file, after all.

Comment: Yes, `Daten` is my public class (includes `GAME, PLATFORM, RELEASED` ) @Fildor What exactly do you meean by Collection? I did all of this before with a text file, but now they told me to do it with a XML File. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: BTW: The reason for the observed behavior: _"The path parameter can be a file name, including a file on a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) share. **If the file exists, it is overwritten;** otherwise, a new file is created."_ - [StreamWriter(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_) (emphasis by me)

Comment: Great, if your model is represented by `Daten`, then you'd need for example a `List<Daten>` which you'll write and read to/from xml. You then can browse that list, add to it, remove from it, edit entries.

Comment: How would one write that code?

Comment: That's really too broad for SO. I'd recommend to watch some beginner's tutorial on YT or something similar to get the basics. Or maybe you are more of a book-learner? If you are a German Speaker, there is http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/visual_csharp_2012/ - somewhat dated, but good enough for a start (before spending money).

Comment: Thank you very much! Will do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, you want to serialize multiple instances into XML.

You could try the following code to get it.

```
   Private void BtnSave_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
    Daten daten=new Daten();
    daten.GAME=txtGame.Text;
    daten.PLATFORM=txtPlatform.Text;
    datem.RELEASED=txtReleased.Text;
    List<Daten> lisrt=new List<Daten>();
    String path=”d:\\gameregister.xml”;
    if(File.Exists(path))
    {
    StreamReader read=new StreamReader(path);
    XmlSerializer xc=new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Daten>));
    list=(List<Daten>)xc.Deserialize(read);
    read.Close();
    Textwriter writer=new StreamWriter(path);
    list.Add(daten);
    xc.Serialize(writer,list);
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(“Serialization succeeded again!;”);
    }
    else
    {
    list.Add(daten);
    XmlSerializer xs=new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Daten>));
    Textwriter writer=new StreamWriter(path);
    xs.Serialize(writer,list);
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(“Serialization successful!”);
    }
   }
```